# Appending previous and next buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Trying to append PREVIOUS/NEXT function in my website.  When the next button is clicked, I want the current tab move to the right next to it.

```
<div class="nav">
        <div id="prev" class="previous" style="display:none">
            <a href="#">Prvious</a>
        </div>
        <div id="prevempty">
        </div>
        <div id="crumbs">
            <ul>
                <li id="li1" class="current"><a href="#1" class="first" value="one" onclick="MenuFunction(1);">One</a></li>
                <li id="li2"><a id="li2A" href="#2" value="two" onclick="MenuFunction(2);">Two</a></li>
                <li id="li3"><a href="#3" value="three" onclick="MenuFunction(3);">Three</a></li>
                <li id="li4"><a href="#4" value="four" onclick="MenuFunction(4);">Four</a></li>
                <li id="li5"><a href="#5" value="five" onclick="MenuFunction(5);">Five</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="nxt" class="next">
            <a href="#">Next</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: what you have done so far , update your MenuFunction()

Comment: -1 for "some1" and not showing the code.

Comment: Based on what you have here, I'm thinking you could store which tab you're on in an HTML element. Default that value to 1 and update it whenever `MenuFunction()` is called. Then when you click your previous and next links they can call `PreviousMenu()` and `NextMenu()`, respectively, and those functions can access the value you stored. Let me know if you need an example and whether or not you're using jQuery and I'll post it as an answer if need be.

Comment: function switchTopPic(direction) {
  var map = { prev: 'last', next: 'first' },
      current = $("#nav .top-pic"),
      target = current[direction]("a");
  if( target.length === 0 ) {
    target = $("#nav a")[map[direction]]();
  }
  current.removeClass("top-pic");
  target.addClass("top-pic");
}

$('#nxt, #prev').click(function () { switchTopPic(this.id) });

Comment: @Samo yes. i have implemented click functions too for this li id's.. pls share some example. thanks

Comment: I was going to post an answer but Vikas Duhan's answer looks fine and doesn't require any additional values to be stored in the html.

Answer (score 1):

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#nxt").click(function(){
        $("#prev").show(); 
            $(".current").next().addClass("current").end().removeClass("current"); 
           if($(".current").attr("id") == "li5")
           {
             $("#nxt").hide();
           }
      });

    $("#prev").click(function(){
     $("#nxt").show();
     $(".current").prev().addClass("current").end().removeClass("current"); 
     if($(".current").attr("id") == "li1")
     {
        $("#prev").hide();
     }
   });
});
```